# ant iterate over files

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I want to iterate over a list of jars (undefined number) and add them all to the jar file.
To add them I plan to use something like this:

```
<jar id="files" jarfile="all.jar">
   <zipfileset src="first.jar" includes="**/*.java **/*.class"/>
   <zipfileset src="second.jar" includes="**/*.java **/*.class"/>
</jar>
```

but how do I iterate over them? I don't have ant-contrib

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

If you do not have access to [`ant-contrib` `For` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html), you may end up to have to define your [custom Task](http://www.nabble.com/New-iterating-task-td21069242.html) for doing what you need...

If you have `ant1.6` and above, you can also try [`subant`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html) (see [New Ant 1.6 Features for Big Projects](http://www.oracle.com/technology/pub/articles/bodewig_ant1.6.html)):

> If you use `<subant>`'s `genericantfile` attribute it kind of works like `<antcall>` invoking a target in the same build file that contains the task.
>   Unlike `<antcall>`, `<subant>` takes a list or set of directories and will invoke the target once for each directory setting the project's base directory.
>
> This is useful if you want to perform the exact same operation in an arbitrary number of directories.

Comment: yes, that would be the correct answer! works fine for me! thanks for the info, see also http://www.softwarebyrichard.com/content/iterating-through-directory-ant

Answer (score 4):

Just use `zipgroupfileset` with the Ant [Zip task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)

```
<zip destfile="out.jar">
    <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</zip>
```

This will flatten all included jar libraries' content.

Comment: I tried this , and it works -  But I encounter class not exist errors when I run the jar - it's as if it doesn't know they're there (but it does compile...)